# JQuery checked item CheckBoxList

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I try to checked specific item in CheckBoxList with JQuery client side in user control?

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:AppCon %>"     
    SelectCommand="SELECT DesF, val, DesGrpId FROM dbo.tblDes WHERE (DesGrpId = @DesGrpId)">    
</asp:SqlDataSource>

<asp:CheckBoxList ID="CheckBoxList1" runat="server" DataTextField="DesF" DataValueField="val"
    DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
```

Comment: what is the condition for specific item?

Comment: a quick recommandation: Move away from this style of writing T-SQL code inside your UI markup. Refer to: http://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/working-with-data-(entity-framework-tutorial)

Comment: this is an text separate whit ',' example : '1,2,3'

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Server side Control:

```
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="ChkList" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem Text ="a" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text ="b" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text ="c" Value="3"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:CheckBoxList>
```

Client Side Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        var str = "1,2";
        var list = $('#<%= ChkList.ClientID%> input');
        list.each(function (index) {
            item = $(this);
            if (str.indexOf(item.val()) != -1) {
                item.attr('checked', true);
            }
        });
    });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you trying to get all the checked items using jQuery? If so just use

```
var checkedItems = $('#parentDivOfCheckBox').find('input:checked');
```

Comment: In that case you have to do something like this $('#chkListParent').find('input:checkbox').each(function(){ if(this.val == 'something') { $(this).attr('checked','checked');}; });